# Get last execution time of script python

Tags: python

Im writting a script in Python that takes as an input a timestamp. For the first execution, it should be something as the now() function. However, for further executions, the input parameter should be the last execution time of the same script. This is being done to avoid getting duplicates results.

Can anyone give me a clue please?

Comment: Since you need to remember it between runs, have you considered: write the timestamp to file when the script runs, when it starts simply check if the file is there and use it, or generate what you need.

Comment: You can use time.sleep() and then make a minus calculation the first timestamp with the last one.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no "last executed" attribute for files. Some operating systems have a "last accessed" attribute, but even if that's updated on execution, it would *also* be updated any time the file was read, which is probably not what you want.

If you need to be able to store information between runs, you'll need to save that data somewhere. You could write it to a file, save it to a database, or write it to a caching service, such as memcached.